# Vue emit will not be important in other component

Tags: vue.js, eventemitter, emit

I am making a vue history quiz app, I have my questions retrived from an API. I want to show the questions, the correct answers and the user’s answers at the ResultScreen view. The way I have gone about it is to push the question into an array and $emit it. I can see it being stored in my vue tools, but for some reason it does not show in the component I want to show it in and consequently in on the resultScreeen.

The currentQuestion is an object that holds the question and the answers.

[the code that emits the array.]

```
storeQuestion: function (value) {
      value = this.submitData.questionArray1
      this.$emit('storeData', value)
      console.log(value, 'my pants are on fire')
    }
```

[shows vue tools at it has been stored.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ry2W.png)

[the component where I want to project it and the function that will not show the question.]

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <QuizQuestion
      v-if="questions.length"
      :currentQuestion="questions[index]"
      @storeData="storeQuestion"
                  />
    <p v-if="questions">{{ questions }}</p>
    <p v-else=""> loading.....</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
// import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import QuizQuestion from '@/components/QuizQuestion.vue'
// se på gameplay hvor vi returner numcorrect, numtotal og numpoints, vi må se på hvordan vi kan importere verde
export default {
  name: 'GameOver',
  components: {
    QuizQuestion
  },
  data () {
    return {
      questions: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    storeQuestion: function (value) {
      this.questions = value
      alert(value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
this.submitData.questionArray1.push(this.currentQuestion.question)
```

Comment: Rather than linking to external images that may not exist in the future, copy-paste into your question. 

Comment: ok sorry, first post here

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your template, specifically, this line:

```
<p v-if="questions">{{ storeQuestion() }}</p>
```

Because the method `storeQuestion` does not `return` a string value, it returns `undefined` regardless of what the value of `questions` is.

Without knowing the shape of the data being stored in `questions` is, it's hard to know exactly what code you want, but I suspect you want something like:

```
<p v-if="questions">{{ questions.text }}</p>
```

...or perhaps...

```
<p v-if="questions">{{ questions[index].text }}</p>
```

...or the like.

However, ancillary to your question about how to display something, your data structure is confusing me. I would expect a data variable called `questions` to be an Array, not at Object (especially since you're using Array access methods (such as `.length` and `questions[index]` on it. I suspect you'll have some additional changes to make, but that's beyond of the scope of your question about displaying info in the `v-if` statement.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, I should change my questions object to a string? Even though the data I am passing from the component is an array?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is, whatever is between the `{{ whatever }}` in your template needs to be a string. Currently, the return value of `storeQuestion()` is `undefined`. If you provided more information about the current shape of your data, I could be more concrete about what it could / should be.

Comment: ok I will try and give you the details, ask me if I am forgetting something. I am retriving questions from an API, they are projected onto a quizquestion component which shows it on a gamePlay view. I am trying to get the info which I manage to project in the gamePlay view on the resultScreen view. I have pushed this information onto arrays, when I console.log them they work. When I try and console.log value in the GameOver component it is undefined. So I think the problem is with how I retrive the data stored. What do you think? And thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: When I asked for the "shape of the data", I'm asking whether it's an Array, an Object, and what the keys of the Object are. A helpful answer would be `[ {firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Jones"} ]`. I understand your data is questions and not names. That's just an example.

Comment: Now, what have you changed your template to? Again, the `storeQuestion()` should NOT be in your template.

Comment: sorry, storeData has an array with the stored questions in it. The array is inside the payload in the vue tools. I changed questions to a string and it atleast removed the errors. I also put question instead of storeData method in the template.

Comment: However it is still not displayed. I need the storeData method to actually get the value from the quizquestion component

Comment: In your `storeQuestions()` function, what is output to the console when you `console.log` ???

Comment: And, again, what is the shape of your data? `[ {questionText: "", id: ""} ]` ??? What are the keys of your question object? Third time asking. 

Comment: Can you actually update your question above to reflect the state of your code now?

Comment: hey I updated the question and added from where I get the value, as I wrote the currentQuestion is an object on the quizQuestion component. Sorry for not answering your question correctly, put on my newbie record :P